# Beginner logic: negated "&" without using disjunction

Tags: logic

I'm working through the exercise in *Logic* by Paul Tomassi and have got myself stuck on the following problem.

Prove the validity of the following sequent.

$ (P\land Q)\to \sim R: R\to(P\to \sim Q) $

So far, the book has introduced:

- conjunctions and the rules for & insertion and removal
- conditionals and rules modus ponens, modus tollens and conditional proof insertion
- biconditionals and their insertion and extraction
- negation - modus tollens and double negative insertion and extraction.

The book has *not* introduced disjunction yet, so the challenge is to prove the validity of the sequent without recourse to the rules around disjunction. The book suggests it should be easy using modus tollens and the double negative rule. The author's note suggests the proof should require 11 lines.

Every time I approach it I go down the following line, which I think is a dead end.

{1}  1. $\qquad (P \land Q)\to \sim R \qquad \qquad $  premise

{1}  2. $\quad \ \ \sim \sim R \to \sim (P\land Q) \quad \ \ \ \ \ \ 1,MT$

{1}  3.  $\quad \ \ \ R \to \sim (P\land Q) \quad \qquad \quad  $ 2, DNE

And this is where I get stuck. The rest would be trivial if I could show that

$\sim (P\land Q) : (P \to \sim Q)$

While that's intuitively obvious, I don't see how I can get there without using DeMorgan's Laws and disjunctive syllogism.

Am I missing something incredibly obvious?

Thanks,

Billy.

Comment: Can you maybe write a title that describes your actual quesiton?

Comment: Apologies - I've just come across an answer to the exact question already on the forum (entitled "Modus Tollens proof).

Comment: Use *de Morgan's Law* and *Implication Equivalence*.